# Finding size of 'shortest range of indices' which lookup all unique path is passed

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

Given an array of String, Finding the size of '**shortest range of indices**' which lookup all unique path is passed.

Example, `A = { E, R, E, R, A, R, T, A }`, it should be **5**. As we can see, ranges of `A[2] = E and A[6] = T` contains all unique path. (In this case, E, R, A, T)

I can solved with multiple loop like below. (solved by Kotlin.)

```
fun problem(array: Array<String>): Int {
    if (array.isEmpty()) return 0
    val unique = array.distinct()
    var result = 200000
    for (i in 0 until A.size) {
        val tempSet = HashSet<String>()
        val remaining = A.sliceArray(i until array.size)
        var count = 0

        while (true) {
            tempSet.add(remaining[count])
            if (unique.size == tempSet.size) break
            count++

            if (count == remaining.size) {
                count = 200000
                break
            }
        }

        result = Math.min(result, count + 1)
    }

    return result
}
```

But when a large array (about 100,000) comes in, I don't know how to reduce the time. How can i do?

Some Test case:

1. [E, R, E, R, A, R, T, A] -> 5. Because [2..6] contains all unique path. (E, R, A, T)
2. [C, A, A, R, C, A, A, R] -> 3. Because [3..5] contains all unique path. (C, A, R)
3. [R, T, A, R, A, R, E, R] -> 6. Because [1..6] contains all unique path. (T, A, R, E)
4. [A, R, R, C, T, E, A, R] -> 5. Because [2..6] contains all unique path. (R, C, T, E, A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem might be effectively solved with "two-pointers" approach.

Make dictionary structure containing char as key and counter as value (in the simplest case - array of int)

Set two indexes L and R in 0.

Move R right, for current char increment counter of corresponding dict element.
When dict size (in case of array - number of non-zero elements) becomes equal to `unique`  , stop

Now move L right, for current char decrement counter of corresponding dict element, removing element when counter becomes zero. When dict size becomes smaller than `unique`, stop. At the last step L..R interval contains all possible items.

Continue with R and so on

Choose the shortest interval during scanning.

Python code for alike question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52995072/what-is-a-faster-version-of-this-code-instead-of-the-double-for-loop-python/52995516#52995516)

Comment: I tried to understand, but for me it feels a bit abstract. Exactly from 'Not move L right' part. If possible, can you give some actual implementation or similar link?

Comment: Answers for alike questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000919/minimum-window-of-days-required-to-travel-all-cities/47002611#47002611),  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046188/find-number-of-subarrays-with-specified-number-of-odd-integers/46046749#46046749) but cannot find my answer with code (it definitely exists)

Comment: Finally found [one of them :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52995072/what-is-a-faster-version-of-this-code-instead-of-the-double-for-loop-python/52995516#52995516)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "all unique path" I will interpret to mean "all possible values".

For a string of length `n` with `k` unique values this is solvable in time `O(n log(k))` using both a dictionary and a priority queue.  The key ideas are this:

1. On a first pass, find all possible values.
2. The second time around, keep a dictionary `most_recently_found` of where each value was most recently found.
3. Keep a priority queue `longest_since` of which value it has been the longest since it has been found.
4. Keep a running minimum of the shortest gap.

And now when you go back through and have found all the values, you follow per iteration logic that looks something like this:

```
most_recently_found[current_value] = current_position
oldest = longest_since.top()
if current_value == oldest.value:
    while oldest.position() != most_recently_found[oldest.position()]:
        longest_since.pop()
        longest_since.push({value: top.value, position: most_recently_found[oldest.position()]
        oldest = longest_since.top()
if current_position - oldest.position() < best_gap:
    best_gap = current_position - oldest.position()
```

The point being that for each value found, you have to update the dictionary (`O(1)`), might have to take it off the priority queue (`O(k)`), might have to put something new on the priority queue (`O(k)`) and might have to do some arithmetic (`O(1)`).  Hence `O(n log(k))` for everything.

Comment: The core idea is understandable, but it is difficult to understand clearly how it really works. If possible, Can you give some actual implementation or similar link which is written in JVM language?

Comment: @Akari Sorry. I don't use any JVM languages or have a JVM environment set up.  So a JVM based implementation is more than I am willing to contribute for free.